# Specify Apache Tomcat "lib" folder in Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, catalina

In [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) 9, the [*JNDI Resources How-To*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) page has a section at the bottom, [*Adding Custom Resource Factories*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories).

To write a class that implements the JNDI service provider `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` interface, the doc says:

> You will need to compile this class against a class path that includes all of the JAR files in the $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory.

That `lib` folder contains:

```
websocket-api.jar
tomcat-jni.jar
tomcat-util-scan.jar
tomcat-util.jar
tomcat-websocket.jar
tomcat-i18n-pt-BR.jar
tomcat-i18n-ru.jar
tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-i18n-ko.jar
tomcat-i18n-cs.jar
tomcat-i18n-de.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
jaspic-api.jar
jsp-api.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
ecj-4.12.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-storeconfig.jar
annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
```

➥ How do I satisfy this requirement in a Maven-driven project?

I certainly do not want all those jars bundled into the resulting WAR file of my web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from the docs what is *really* needed but, in general, you will have something like the following in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jndi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jndi</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The key is the `provided` scope.  This means that the library is needed for compilation but should not be included as part of the packaging.  In other words, it is provided by the destination deployment environment.

Having said that, the link you provide is for writing a **custom** resource factory.  It will not be a `.war` file but will instead be a `.jar` that you would install into Tomcat to extend it.  Is that what you're after?  If you just need to do a JNDI lookup then the chunk of XML I provided will work for your code.

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a custom resource factory. The default resource factory in Tomcat 9 for a JDBC DataSource instantiates a `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`. Instead, I want a `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource` object, not from a pool. I am hoping to make this a part of my web app, bundled in the WAR flle, not a separate JAR.

Comment: Actually, it seems the resource factory may already be written. I found the [`org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/PGObjectFactory.html) class built into the classic Postgres JDBC driver. This class implements the critical  `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` interface. So my Question here may be moot for my own situation.